# Reuse field list and FROM clause in UNION ALL query

Tags: mysql

I'd like to create a view that combines search results over the same data with different search criteria. Now it looks like this:

```
SELECT <huge_field_list>
FROM <big_table_list>
WHERE <first_condition_list>

UNION

SELECT <huge_field_list>
FROM <big_table_list>
WHERE <second_condition_list>
```

Is there any way I can reuse the field list and FROM clause for the query to look less ugly?
I tried combining WHERE clauses using OR, but it makes the query awfully slow, because both condition blocks use different index.

Comment: Maybe create index containing all the fields from both where clauses?

Comment: No, they're both way too long.

Comment: @Alma Do, I did mention this in the question.